# Can I use an external config file AND also have child elements in the source web.config?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

for reasons that aren't worth conversing I was wondering if it's possible to externalize a section of a web.config with some settings AND also have some settings in the original .config?

Like So:

web.config:

```
 <connectionStrings configSource = "conn.config">
    <add name="blahblah3" connectionString="Blah3>
 </connectionStrings>
```

conn.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Blahblah" 
             connectionString="blah1" />
        <add name="blahblah2"
             connectionString="blah2" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

Is the above possible?

Comment: How about using [SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) instead?

Comment: Well, the problem is in the deployment process.. the guy clones the machine and moves it into a different environment and he just wants to "drop in the config file" it's just a few app settings that change.. however, we're pressing for the standard "build" routine

Comment: I know you said it wasn't worth conversing but then why not keep a single web.config file and change only the section that needs to be changed when cloning the machine?

Comment: The problem is additions added by the other dev's.. sometimes (a lot of times?) a new app setting will be required.. and then the "good copy" needs to be updated.. which is why it'd be nice to have an internal "section" which get's included with the "clone" and an external config which can be dropped in. Of course both sections have to do with the app settings.. I didnt start this, and most likely i'll get them to a "build and deploy" process.. but for now its somewhat cumbersome and i'm wondering if there is even a soluiton